# Seaborn Bar Plot Offsetting Values by Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I am trying to create a bar plot from a dataset that has descending integers as the y values, and a last name as the x values. All values seem to be plotted properly, but the first few values seem to default to having an error bar that offsets the full bar itself. Instead of going up to the actual value, it stops at the middle of the error bar, and then the top of the error bar goes to the actual value of the x value. What could be going on here and why is the offset automatically happening for those values?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 50)
pd.set_option("display.min_rows", 30)

sns.set(rc = {"figure.figsize": (15, 8)})

df = pd.read_csv("skaters.csv")

df[["name", "last_name"]] = df["name"].str.split(" ", 1, expand = True)

df = df.rename(columns = {"name": "first_name"})
df["faceoffsWon"] = df["faceoffsWon"].astype(int)

smalldf = df.sort_values(by = ["faceoffsWon"], ascending = False).head(30)
plot = sns.barplot(data = smalldf, x = "last_name", y = "faceoffsWon")
```

[image]

Comment: The same `last_name` seems to appear multiple times in the top 30, probably with a different first name (e.g. "John Smith" and "Jane Smith").  (Note that only 25 bars are plotted). A solution could be to join first and last name together (maybe with a newline `\n` between them.  After `ax = sns.barplot(....)` you could use e.g. `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)` to rotate the ticks.

Comment: You could try `ax = sns.barplot(x=smalldf.index, y=smalldf["faceoffsWon"])` followed by `ax.set_xticklabels(smalldf["last_name"]))`.  That should show the full dataframe including the duplicate names.